# Hide elements based on a specific element value

Tags: woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and I’m importing custom fields like “color”, “length”, etc (around 10 fields) but not all product have values for these fields. Is there a way to hide the whole element of the value is empty or null. On the front end the elements show like this:
Length: 10cm
Height: 20cm
So basically if there is no length for a specific product I want to hide it.

Link to see: (check product extra details. In this example I only want to show the diameter and hide the rest since they are empty)

https://qadeemarabia.com/product/3d-bird-cookie-jar-off-white-matt/

Comment: In the Product attributes section in product edit page, value of **Product Weight** or **Product Width**  what are? Is it _cm_ or _kg_ without any number? And do you mean to hide the numberless properties?

Comment: The CM and KG are the units which are put after the value so they always appear in the template even if the attribute has no value. If you open the link you will see that only the last attribute has value (for this product) so I want to hide the whole lines that have no values (and they differ for each product) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter to delete empty items. My hypothesis for the empty condition is that the value is zero. You can change the condition according to what you need:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'ywp_hide_ptoperties_with_empty_values', 10, 2 );
function ywp_hide_ptoperties_with_empty_values( $attributes, $product ) {
    // Loop to check values
    foreach( $attributes as $attr ) {
        $new_attr   = array();

        // Your condition for check value is empty
        // You can use 'trim' etc.
        $value      = floatval( $attr['value'] );

        // Check value is 0 here means value is empty
        // and empty value skipped
        if( $value != 0 ) {
            $new_attr[] = $attr;
        }
    }

    return $new_attr;
}
```

This code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro... I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark this solution as the correct answer ;)